# Good similarity measure for comparing users

Tags: recommendation-engine, euclidean-distance, cosine-similarity

I want to compare users based on responses to 10 questions. My original idea was to resolve each question to an integer [1, 5], but this idea won't work all the time. For example:

`vec1 = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]`

`vec2 = [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]`

`get_cos_sim(vec1, vec2) = 1`

So even though the users responded completely dissimilarly, the vectors are the same.

I would like to get similar users based on similarity of their responses to each question. So for a given question, if person A's response resolved to 1 and person B's response resolved to 2, the similarity between the responses in those questions would be higher than person A's and person C's response, who answered 4.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the metric I would use:

Take the absolute value of the difference between each answer, sum all of those values, the similarity is the inverse.

Comment: I thought about doing that but the problem is: take a 2 element vector `[0, 5]` and `[5, 0]`. Then the algo would return 10 for each vector, although the users answered the questions fundamentally differently. I was thinking euclidean distance.

Comment: Right, take the inverse. Similarity for that vector would be 0.1

Comment: Similarity for [5, 0], [5, 0] would be infinity. Similarity for [3, 1], [5, 2] would be 0.333.

Comment: So as the metric approaches infinity the more similar and the closer to 0 the least similar?

Comment: Well, the largest positive non-infinite result is being "1 off". Like [4, 5], [5, 5] is 1/1 which is 1. So the domain of the metric is really from just above 0 to 1 and you can clamp divide by zero at 1